# Finding if a list item is in a filename

Tags: python-3.x, loops, substring

Suppose I have a filename like: `D_Passaic_F01_NBR_E0003.tif` thats in a folder that I am iterating through using Python. Suppose I want to get all of the files between E0001 and E0010. I might make a list like: `select_libr = ['E0001', 'E0002', 'E0003', 'E0003', 'E0005', 'E0006', 'E0007', 'E0008', 'E0009', 'E0010']`. Using this list, how can I check the filename will iterating through the directory to just pull out those key files?

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if (filename.startswith("D_")) and (filename.endswith(".tif") or filename.endswith(".tiff")):
        print(os.path.join(directory, filename))
    else:
        continue
```

What I want to do is something like: `...and (item in select_libr in filename)` but I am not sure the correct syntax here. Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried: ` if (re.fullmatch(r"D_.*_(E\d{4})\.tif", filename)):
                  print(os.path.join(directory, filename))`, but that just printed everything.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read correctly. Does `r"D_.*_(E00(?:10|0\d))\.tiff?"` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to extract the number from `Exxx` and then do what you want with it. For example,

`E(\d+)\.tiff?$` will match `E`, then one or more digits, then `.tif`, followed by an optional `f` at the end of the string. More importantly, it captures the digits as a group and allows us to pull just the digits out of the match object. [Try it](https://regex101.com/r/h4m88T/7)

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    research = re.search(r"E(\d+)\.tiff?", filename)
    if research: # If there was a match
        fnum = research.group(1) # This is the string "0003", for example
        # Then do whatever you want with it
        if 0 <= int(fnum) <= 10:
            print(filename)
```

If you want to allow arbitrary values, I highly recommend using a `set` instead of a `list` to store those values, because checking for membership in a set is cheaper than in a list.

```
select_libr = {'E0001', 'E0002', 'E0003', 'E0003', 'E0005', 'E0006', 'E0007', 'E0008', 'E0009', 'E0010'}
```

And change the regex so that the `E` is also captured: `(E\d+)\.tiff?` [Try it](https://regex101.com/r/h4m88T/6)

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    research = re.search(r"(E\d+)\.tiff?", filename)
    if research: # If there was a match
        fnum = research.group(1) # This is the string "E0003", for example
        # Then do whatever you want with it
        if fnum in select_libr:
            print(filename)
```

To ensure your filename starts with a `D_`, you can prepend `^D_.*?` to the other regexes. This looks for a `D_` at the start of the string, followed by as many of any character. Everything else can remain the same. [Try it](https://regex101.com/r/h4m88T/5)